# Custom command inside soul package's \hl

Tags: macros, highlighting, soul

I'm having trouble with the `soul` package and its `\hl` command. The `soul` package's manual says I should not nest `soul` commands, which I didn't. `\textsc` works inside `\hl`. However, the following throws an `Argument of \name has an extra }` error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
% this one works
Hello \hl{\textsc{Calvin}}!

% this one will throw an error, with both soul and soulutf8
Hello \hl{\name{Calvin}}!
\end{document}
```

Am I missing something in the way that `\newcommand` works? Is this a known problem with the `soul` package? Any other suggestions for highlighting text - which may be longer and thus needs to be wrapped?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 8):

See the documentation of soul "Adding font commands" (page 15).

```
\soulregister{\name}{1}
```