# Argument of \someCustomCommand has an extra } encountered when command is put in \ul. How to fix this?

Tags: macros, soul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom command inside soul package's \hl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20053/custom-command-inside-soul-packages-hl)

To make the document easier to understand (and easier to write), I have defined:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

I have used `\code{some code}` in `hyperref` and many many other places and everything has been fine.

However, now I used it with `\ul` (from `soul` package), like this:

```
\ul{\code{Hello}} world
```

and I get this warning:

```
! Argument of \code has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.52 \ul{\code{Hello}}
                       world
```

Is theresomething wrong with the way I am defining my command? If I use `\ul{\texttt{Hello}}` there is no problem. Shouldn't my code be effectively reduced to that?!

**Note:** I'm not looking for `\code{\ul{Hello}}` as an answer or similar things that change the text. The main reason is that I generate the text from another file that may decide to put the underline around the code. It would be much more difficult for me to change that order in text, than to fix the definition, or even replace all `\code`s with `\texttt`s and forget about the macro altogether!

Comment: Funny how I didn't find that question! :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [section 5.2 of the `soul` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf#subsection.5.2):

> To convince `soul` not to feed font switching (or other) commands to the analyzer,
>   but rather to execute them immediately, they have to be registered, too. The
>   `\soulregister` macro takes the `\soulregister` name of a command name and either `0` or `1` for
>   the number of arguments:
>
> `\soulregister{<command name>}{<number of arguments>}`

That means even though `\code` is essentially `\texttt`, you have to make sure that [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) treats it appropriately by using `\soulregister{\code}{1}`.

#### Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\soulregister{\code}{1}
\begin{document}
\ul{\code{Hello}} world
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great thanks! Could I ask a side question that is probably related? I see in section 6.4 of the manual how to use `soul` in section headings. It is very vague, but fine. However, it says how to apply a `soul` command to the whole section, while I need to write something like `\section{Only \ul{this} is underlined}`. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: @Shahbaz Using `\ul` and friends in sectioning commands should work fine (at least in the standard classes like `article` etc.). You have to watch out, however, when using this in combination with [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref): In this case, you'll need to use something like `\section{Only \texorpdfstring{\ul{this}}{this} is underlined}`.

Comment: You are awesome!