# Underline text with background (soul and ulem nesting)

Tags: highlighting, text-decorations, soul, ulem

I'm using `soul`'s `\hl` to set background for the paragraph parts and `ulem`'s `\uline` to underline text.

The problem is what I cant underline text for text with background.

Initial doc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\bg}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\definecolor{ColorFg}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{ColorBg}{HTML}{008000}

\begin{document}

{\color{ColorFg}\bg{ColorBg}{Some Text}} another text.

\end{document}
```

[image: initial doc]

I want to underline `Text`:

```
{\color{ColorFg}\bg{ColorBg}{Some \uline{Text}}} another text.
```

it fails with `! Argument of \UL@on has an extra }.`

I tried to use `\soulregister{\uline}{1}` ([solution from this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46869/argument-of-somecustomcommand-has-an-extra-encountered-when-command-is-put-in)) - no errors and no underlined tex.

Is it possible to underline text with background color (maybe I have to use another packages)?

PS `soul` docs provides solution for nested commands, but it's not useful for me since line breaks will not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Simply enclose the `\uline{}` inside a pair of braces. You do not need any other package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\bg}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\definecolor{ColorFg}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{ColorBg}{HTML}{008000}

\begin{document}

{\color{ColorFg}\bg{ColorBg}{Some {\uline{Text}}}} another text.

\end{document}
```

And here is the output,

[image]

---

**Question on answer**

Could somebody please tell me why the following vanishes "Text"?

```
{\color{ColorFg}\bg{ColorBg}{Some \protect\uline{Text}}} another text.
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you have for example `{\uline{Text Text}}`. In this case you can use `\mbox{\uline{Text Text}}`. It doesn't work, in any case, if the contents of `\uline` has to break a line...

Comment: Hm, true. @karlkoeller is right.

Comment: I had to use `\underline` instead of `\uline` as in `\hl{highlighted {\underline{highlighted and underlined}} highlighted}`