# How can I use `\uline` from the `ulem` package to underline text inside a `\colorbox`?

Tags: formatting, highlighting, ulem, underline, colorbox

**Screenshot:**

I have the following code:

```
\uline{No underlining for \colorbox{lightgray}{everything} inside the colorbox.}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I get a continuous line for the text inside `\colorbox`, too?

---

**MCVE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\uline{No underlining for \colorbox{lightgray}{everything} inside the colorbox.}

\end{document}
```

---

**Constraints:**

I cannot use `soul` and I think plain `\underline` doesn't look very good. (By the way, those who *can* use `soul` should have a look at [Underline text with background (soul and ulem nesting)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142429/underline-text-with-background-soul-and-ulem-nesting) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to underline in a box first:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\begin{document}

\sbox0{\uline{\hspace{\fboxsep}everything\hspace{\fboxsep}}}
\uline{No underlining for \colorbox{lightgray}{\hspace{-\fboxsep}\usebox0\hspace{-\fboxsep}} inside the colorbox.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, okay. Thanks! :-) That's more complicated than I thought it would be. I mean `\colorbox` is inside of `\uline`, I thought there would be a simple way to raise the "z-index" of the line or something like that... Can you explain *why* the line doesn't show up in front of the colorbox?

Comment: @Jayjayyy not exactly, I started to trace but didn't have much time yesterday so i just nested the uline (the hspace are so the line spans over the fboxsep padding in the colorbox)

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a valid answer to the question. :-) Unfortunately, I cannot use it like this because I cannot change the content inside `\uline` I'm afraid. Do you think there is hope for a solution without nesting?

Comment: @Jayjayyy you could redefine `\uline so that locally `\colorbox` is defined as I show above, or (given the `\uline` works with `\fbox` someone may suggest a different extension so that it works directly with colorbox..

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that this is possible. Opened a new question [Redefine `\uline` so `\colorbox` is locally defined to have underlined text, too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468307/redefine-uline-so-colorbox-is-locally-defined-to-have-underlined-text-too)