# Make soul and \texttt work together

Tags: typewriter, soul

I was trying to redefine `\texttt` command to make it have background color using package soul. But it seems that it is harder than I thought.

My initial code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
    \hl{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{can we highlight}

\end{document}
```

But it won't run, the error message is:

> Argument of \texttt  has an extra }.

I searched and found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20053/custom-command-inside-soul-packages-hl/20055#20055). The post suggests to use `\soulregister` command. So I add the following line before `\begin{document}`:

```
\soulregister{\texttt}{1}
```

But the error persists. I also found this post, which further suggests to use `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Now my code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
% \renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
%   \hl{\oldtexttt{#1}}
% }

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{
    \hl{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}
\soulregister{\texttt}{1}

\begin{document}

\texttt{can we highlight}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. The error message is

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]

It seems like rabbit hole of issues. Can you point out what has gone wrong? How to fix this seemingly simple problem?

**Edit:**

I am using Pandoc to convert Markdown file to PDF. The underlying LaTeX command for Markdown inline code is `\texttt`. But there is no background color. That is why I want to combine soul and `\texttt`.

I have tried the solution of @egreg and @daleif. They both work for standard alone tex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt

% \renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
% {\ttfamily\hl{#1}}
% }

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{%
    \hl{\ttfamily#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{can we highlight}

\end{document}
```

But if I put it in a file `head.tex` and compile Markdown to PDF, there are still errors. The content of `head.tex` is:

```
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{%
    \hl{\ttfamily#1}%
}
```

Content of `test.md` is

```
`some inline words`
```

If I try to generate PDF using the new header:

```
pandoc -H head.tex -s test.md -o test.pdf
```

there occurs another error:

> Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

Answer (score 7):

The `soul` macros are rather special, it works on a macro level this cannot handle that the contents has "macros" in it.

I would not overload `\texttt` like that, make a special macro for it.

BTW: This works `{\ttfamily\hl{#1}}`

Answer (score 1):

The working of `\texttt` is essentially absorbing its argument and issuing `\ttfamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{%
    \hl{\ttfamily#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{can we highlight}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, it would be better to use a different command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\colorlet{mycolor}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{mycolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hltt}[1]{%
    \hl{\ttfamily#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\hltt{can we highlight}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to protect the end-of-lines.